# What is this method of sketching a third degree curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

> $$u(x)=\frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2}-\delta x-\frac{\alpha x^3}{3}$$
> $\omega,\delta,\alpha$ are real and positive. Sketch the typical plots of $u(x)$ and identify extrema if any.

Now, I understand how to sketch a cubic polynomial. I take its derivative, find its discriminant (to check number of turning points), and then sketch accordingly.

However, the solution given for this problem is intriguing. They have done this:

> We can define $D=m^2\omega^4-4\alpha\delta$ and $D'=m^2\omega^4-\dfrac{16}3\alpha\delta$. There are four possibilities:
>
> [image]

I understand that $u'(x)=-\alpha x^2+m\omega^2x-\delta$, hence, $D_{u'(x)}=m^2\omega^4-4\alpha\delta$. But, I do not understand from where they got $D'$, and how they have used it to sketch the graphs.Please help me understand this. Thank you!

---

*INPhO 2011 - [Question paper (p21)](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inpho2011-Q.pdf) and [Solution (p3)](http://www.aryanclasses.com/NSE/Indian-National-Olympiad/INPHO-2011-solution.pdf) - for reference*

Comment: You qualified NSEP. Congrats bro!

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks :) I hope you also qualified

Comment: :( I couldn't. I missed MI by a few marks. I qualified only for INAO.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Ah, that's sad. Nevermind

Comment: @JaideepKhare What are NSEP and INAO? Is this question relevant to those?

Comment: @Chase this question is from previous year papers of Indian National Physics Olympiad. Abbreviated as INPhO. Its second round for Physics Olympiad in India, whereas NSEP is National Standard Examination in Physics, which first stage examination for Physics Olympiad. INAO, on the other side is Indian National Astronomy Olympiad (second stage for Astronomy Olympiad)

Comment: @JaideepKhare come here, before a mod deletes our chat xD https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71957/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-jaideep-khare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully observe, then you can see that $x=0$ is a solution for the cubic polynomial. So cancelling out $x$ term from the whole expression, we're left with a quadratic, solving that will help us find the remaining roots of the cubic equation. So $D'$ is nothing but the discriminant of quadratic remaining after cancelling out $x$.

The nature of $D'$ helps us in determining the nature of roots of cubic, directly. $D'<0$ implies no real root of the quadratic, I.e. only one root of cubic $x=0$. $D'=0$ suggests the remaining two roots are concurrent. Hence, the graph will touch the x-axis at that point, instead of intersecting. Similarly, you can understand other cases via graphs.

Comment: Hmmm, but the quadratic remaining after cancelling $x$ is $f(x)=-\frac{\alpha x^2}{3}+\frac{m\omega^2x}{2}-\delta$ and $D_{f(x)}=\frac{m^2\omega^4}{4}-4\frac{\delta\alpha}{3}$. Those two don't seem to match :/

Comment: @Gaurang What happens if we multiply $D_{f(x)}$ by $4$?

Comment: Oh! Since we are comparing with zero, we can easily multiply by a constant $k$. Understood!

Comment: @Gaurang Yeah absolutely correct! BTW, you from ALLEN Or FIITJEE? Or anywhere else?

Comment: From Resonance ^_^

Comment: @Gaurang Kota? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71957/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-jaideep-khare).

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention that factor of $4$ (and the fact that it doesn't affect the number of roots) in the answer itself.

Comment: @Gaurang You didn't respond in chat?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Oh dude didn't get the ping :/

Comment: @Gaurang It's ok bro. Btw, are your boards over?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yep, boards over. Reasonably decent performance. Results out in early June. Now thirty days to prep for mains :D Your boards? Dates finalized? Are they just after mains?

Comment: @GaurangTandon My boards started today. Will end on 26th. And Mains, offline, on 8th. Got 12 days for revision. :D

Comment: Cool, I guess you'll have everything fresh in your memory after the boards for the mains exam. Good luck for the boards bro! :D

Comment: @GaurangTandon I just want chemistry to be revised properly. I am not worried about Math and Physics that much. Chemistry Sucks. Specially, "Chemistry in Everyday Life" xD. Thanks btw.

Comment: Exactly! I was the most scared of chemistry and for the exact same reasons! Maths was as easy as skiing on ice, while chem was like rolling on spikes xD Fortunately, I did decently in the latter too.